# Get the ID of the Current div in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am generating a dynamic `id` for my `div` through `v-for` and I have to pass this `id` to a certain function.

```
<div
   v-for="(item, index) in items"
   :key="index"
   :id="'form' + index"
>
   <button onclick="function(<id of the div>)"></button>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the id to the function the same way as you used it in the binding:

```html
<button @click="function('form' + index)"></button>
```

The `v-for` creates block scoped variables that are available to the repeated element and its children.

Also use the `@click` directive instead of `onclick`.  Assuming you had a method called "handler", for example, your component might look like:

```html
<button @click="handler('form' + index)"></button>
```

```js
methods: {
  handler(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }
}
```